# Sencha Touch Custom List Row

Tags: css, list, row, sencha-touch, extjs

I need your help for Ext.List element on Sencha Touch Framework. I have a list that it is refreshed in every 1 second. When there is an update on one row i have to highlight that row. Problem is i use template for the list and template apply the css for whole List. How can i change the design of spesific row?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a template you can call a function to do logic.

There are examples [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.XTemplate).

You are looking for the "Template member functions" section of that doc.  That will let you call a function to decide to add the css class to the element, or data attribute or whatever you decide.

Comment: Thanks ballmw, i think that's the answer of my problem!